# Improving audio (Adobe Audition)

Tags: audio-recording, audio, sound-effects-recording, adobe-audition

I have a recording with sound quality that I would like to improve. Got Adobe Audition software and tried various things in there (mainly different Effects). However, I'm not a professional and whatever I do does not make much of a difference. The software is clearly designed for professionals (too many parameters to change). Thus, I'm seeking some professional advice. Here is [the excerpt of the audio](https://sndup.net/kyr2/). I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some advice on how to improve the quality of the audio (if it is possible). Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure there's much you can do to fix that, even with restoration software, not just a DAW. It sounds like a cheap headset struggling to get past one of the Skype/Zoom-type noise reduction algorithms.

Comment: It has got expander type noise gate which makes quiet periods even more quiet. Then there's low bitrate lossy compression which makes those squeaky chirps. There exists commercial products which claim to be able to guess  what there was before the data compression. Here's an ad of one. No idea does it actually work and definitely not my business. https://www.zynaptiq.com/unchirp/